# How to access another Connect server table in my Local server in SQLyog 7.01?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

In same server name using same database

```
select * from area;(Working Good)
```

Same Servername but Different Database

```
select * from mysql.event(Working Good)
```

Now i am connection TWO Different server i want to access one Remote server database table into local server database table in my sql using SQL YOG 7.01
Examples my server like this

```
root@192.168.12.35
root@192.168.12.89
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is how to access a remote MySQL table from another MySQL server, that can be achieved with the FEDERATED engine (disabled by default in mysql 5.5) os with the CONNECT engine (only available on MariaDB 10).

Here you have the documentation to create such tables in both cases:

- [Creating a FEDERATED table using CONNECTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-create-connection.html). You need to [enable the FEDERATED engine beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210309/how-can-i-enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-after-installation)
- [Connect table types - MySQL/MariaDB table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/connect/connect-table-types/connect-table-types-mysql-table-type-accessing-mysqlmariadb-tables/)

I hope you are not thinking about using it for nothing too serious, as the performance is usually not too good.